# Understanding Azure Compute Managment Resources and Displaying Information

Tags: python, azure

I'd like to print all information that the ComputeManagementClient from the azure.mgmt.compute library offers. I've opened a compute client and found my target vm by matching the name. However when I return this object from my calling function (which is expecting a json formatted object) I get this error:

```
TypeError: <azure.mgmt.compute.models.virtual_machine.VirtualMachine object at 0x10c19b550> is not JSON serializable
```

When I print an object from inside my generating function I get a result like this:

```
{'os_profile': <azure.mgmt.compute.models.os_profile.OSProfile object
at 0x104966650>, 'storage_profile':
<azure.mgmt.compute.models.storage_profile.StorageProfile object at
0x104966710>, 'availability_set': 
<azure.mgmt.compute.models.sub_resource.SubResource object at 
0x104966850>, 'name': u'azure-test-1b', 'tags': {'cluster': u'server', 
'name': u'azure-test-1b', 'service': u'server'}, 
'diagnostics_profile': None, 'vm_id': u'XXXX-XXXX-XXXX', 
'hardware_profile': 
<azure.mgmt.compute.models.hardware_profile.HardwareProfile object at 
0x104966b90>, 'provisioning_state': u'Failed', 'network_profile': 
<azure.mgmt.compute.models.network_profile.NetworkProfile object at 
0x104966bd0>, 'plan': None, 'license_type': None, 'instance_view': 
None, 'type': u'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines', 'id': 
u'/subscriptions/XXXX-XXXX-XXXX/resourceGroups/YYY-YYYY-YYY/providers
/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/azure-test-1b', 'resources': None, 
'location': u'eastus2'}
```

This result looks like a json formatted objet, so I'm not sure why it returns as the object reference. What operation do I call to return the above output? Second question how can I expand the value like the network_profile that are themselves references to objects? Is there a way to return the most complete view of the VM using the azure python sdks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Question 1: Can I get the JSON*

The SDK deserializes the JSON into specific objects, you can have a documentation of the object on ReadTheDocs: http://azure-sdk-for-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

For instance, [VirtualMachine](http://azure-sdk-for-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/azure.mgmt.compute.models.html#azure.mgmt.compute.models.VirtualMachine)

If you really need the JSON and not an object, you have two choices:

- Use raw=True in your call (see [VM.get documentation](http://azure-sdk-for-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/azure.mgmt.compute.operations.html#azure.mgmt.compute.operations.VirtualMachinesOperations.get))
- Use the generic [resource.get](http://azure-sdk-for-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/azure.mgmt.resource.resources.operations.html#azure.mgmt.resource.resources.operations.ResourcesOperations.get) in the azure-mgmt-resource package. You will get [GenericResource](http://azure-sdk-for-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/azure.mgmt.resource.resources.models.html#azure.mgmt.resource.resources.models.GenericResource) object, half parsed with "properties" containing a dict of the properties that applies to your object.

*Question 2: How to get Network details*

You get the id returned in network_profile, parse it and use azure-mgmt-network package to get the details. [There is no faster way currently.](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues/897)

*Question 3: How to get more details about the VM*

The VM object is more precise using the "expand" mode (like running state only available in expand). In your call, use expand="instanceView" (see [VM.get](http://azure-sdk-for-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/azure.mgmt.compute.operations.html#azure.mgmt.compute.operations.VirtualMachinesOperations.get) method)

As a complement, this is the [official sample for VM](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/virtual-machines-python-manage) if it helps.

(I'm the owner of the Azure SDK for Python at MS)